# The maximum memory location my C stack pointer can points to during initialization

Tags: c

Consider the following code in a linux machine with 32 bit OS:

```
void foo(int *pointer){
  int *buf;
  int *buf1 = pointer;
  ....
}
```

What is the maximum memory address buf and buf1 can point to using the above declaration (OS allocates the address)? E.g., can it point to address 2^32-200?

The reason I asked is that I may do pointer arithmetic on these buffers and I am concern that this pointer arithmetic can wrap around. E.g., assume the len is smaller than the size of buf and buf1. Assume some_pointer points to the end of the buffer.

```
unsigned char len = 255;
if(buf + len > some_pointer)
  //do something
if(buf1 + len > some_pointer)
  //do something
```

Comment: Speculating what an indeterminate variable "can" hold is skirting the edge of insanity from the get-go. Trying to attach meaning to that insanity just takes it up a notch.

Comment: 64 or 32 bit? The amount of phisically installed ram is hardly relevant, as your userspace program will usually not work with physicall addresses but virtual ones.

Comment: @MikeMB, thank you for correcting me. It is 32 bit

Comment: @WhozCraig, If I am going to do pointer arithmetic on this, then it will make sense why I asked the question.

Comment: Pointers are unsigned, so theoretically you can get a pointer up to `0xFFFFFFFF`, or 2^32 - 1.  On a 32-bit OS running 32-bit software.

Comment: To detect overflow, the following should work: `if ((buf + len) < buf) { ...overflow detected here... }`

Comment: If i remember correctly, linux will not allow you to use the first and last 4k of address space (but of course, you can still set the address manually to e.g. 0 or 2^32-1) but I'd look for confirmation.

Comment: @ash: This is relying on undefined behavior

Comment: @MikeMB, why is that length checking relying on undefined behavior?

Comment: You are adding a number `len` to a pointer `buf`, correct? And then check if the result wrapped around (is smaller than the original address)? Pointer overflow is undefined behavior. To be precises: E.g. for an array of lenght 10, starting at `buf` the expression `buf+11` yields undefined behavior (`buf+10` - *one past the end* - would be ok)

Comment: For this, it is completely irrelevant, whether `buf` pointed to the address 0, 1000 or 2^32-10.

Comment: @dannycrane: Sorry, my previous comment was a response to ash's suggestion, but if `len` is bigger than the size of your array, then your example code exhibits undefined behavior too.

Comment: @MikeMB, thank you for pointing out this. Assume len is within the size of my array. I updated the post.

Comment: Is this c or c++ by the way? I'm not sure, whether the rules about comparing pointers are exactly the same

Comment: @MikeMB - sounds like you don't really understand what "undefined behavoir" means in this context, or how C/C++ pointers work.  For example, accessing `*(buf + 11)` when buf only has 10 elements (e.g. `char buf[10]`) gives perfectly defined behavoir - it reads one element past the end of the allocated array.

Comment: @ash: `*(buf+11)` equals `buf[11]` reads *two* past the last element (index starts at 0), which is UB. As I wrote, `buf[10]` or `buf+10` is ok.

Comment: True, thanks for correcting my off-by-one mistake.  With that said, reading 2 past the end of an allocated area does give well-defined results, even if most of the time, not the intended results.

Comment: @ash: Are you sure? Can you give a source for it? I've to admit that I almost exclusively write c++ code, so things might be different in C, but in c++ it would definitevly be UB and what you describe is just one of the possible invocations of UB.

Comment: @ash: I think, this is the relevant part of the C-Standard (6.5.6 / 8 from the 2010 working draft N1539): *If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the **behavior is undefined**. If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.*

Comment: So even `buf[10]` would be UB.

Comment: Interesting - I'm looking at the standard here, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1539.pdf, and cannot find that wording.  At least I believe I'm looking at the same standard.  Found it - search didn't work properly.

Comment: OK, I see it now - it's stating that the result of evaluating the expression (i.e. dereferencing the pointer) is undefined, which makes perfect sense - the pointer is pointing outside the "intended" area and may be pointing at non-existent memory.  The math on the pointer, on the other hand, is not UB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88910/discussion-between-mikemb-and-ash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard says that

1. For two elements of an array, the address of the element with the lower subscript will always compare less to the address of the object with the higher subscript.
2. Comparing any two elements that are not part of the same aggregate (array or struct) is **undefined behavior**.

So if `buf + len` and `some_pointer` point to elments in the same array as `buf` (or one past the array), you don't have to worry about wrap arround. If one of them doesn't, you have **undefined behavior** anyway.

Comment: The post said len is smaller than the length of the buffer. I also add a note saying some_pointer points to the end of the buffer.

Comment: @dannycrane: So, why do you need to knwo the possible address of `buf` then?

Comment: @dannycrane: In response to your edits and comments, I've rewritten my answer. Please check, if you still want to have it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't ever rely on the addresses provided by the allocator falling within a specific range. Even if you could show that on a particular Linux setup, `malloc` can only generate addresses between X and Y, there is no guarantee--it could change with any future update. The only guarantee from `malloc` is that successful allocations won't start at `NULL` (address 0 in code, for Linux and most other typical platforms).

Comment: Successful allocations may start at address `0` in theory  (on those systems the null pointer will be different to address 0)

Comment: Are you sure about that? At least in C++, the language has built-in rules about 0 being the `nullptr`. (For instance, pointers can be compared directly against 0 but comparing against any other value would be a type-mismatch violation.)

Comment: This `malloc` documentation also treats 0 as null explicitly: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Malloc-Examples.html

Comment: http://c-faq.com/null/macsochange.html <-- pretty much shoots down the idea of `null` ever being nonzero

Comment: You're mixing up the integer literal `0` with address zero. When integer `0` is converted to pointer it becomes a null pointer, which might not be all-bits-zero (and doesn't represent address zero in either case).

Comment: *shrug* I added vagueness to the post

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for a 32 bit or 64 bit OS.  Whether there's anything usable there, or if you'll get an access violation trying to dereference the pointer, is up to the compiler and OS.

Answer (score 0):

The OS can map pages of physical memory anywhere in the address space.  The addresses you see don’t correspond to physical RAM chips at all.  The OS might, for example, have virtual memory or copy-on-write pages.